# xsl:for-each test a wildcard element

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to loop through some XML until I find an element that contains a string of text.

take a very simple XML example.

```
<document>
  <item>
   <thing1>Fee</thing1>
   <thing2>Fi</thing2>
   <thing3>Fo</thing3>
   <some blah="Thingy">Fum</some>
   <another>I Smell</another>
   <other>Someone</other>
  </item>
</document>
```

I want to be able to search through for any element/s that contains "thing", I have seen this done before with an attribute like so...

```
<xsl:for-each test="contains(@blah,'Thingy')"></xsl:for-each>
```

but I want to search the "thing1, thing2, thing3" and then obtain their `<xsl:value-of select"." />` which will be Fee, Fi, and Fo. I need to exclude the other elements as they aren't going to contain the string "thing"

Comment: `<xsl:for-each test="contains(@blah,'Thingy')">` is not valid syntax: `xsl:for-each` has no `test` attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[contains(name(), 'thing')]">
```

or, to better fit the given example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="*[starts-with(name(), 'thing')]">
```

Both to be called from the context of `item`.

Comment: Thanks @michael.hor257k that nailed it, I was so close on my testing that I was playing with before writing this one up. I missed the [ ] usage. and the name() i tried using text().